# Table doesn't exist but it does (or should)

Tags: php, sql

I'm making a generator and it works fine (paid) but I was trying to make a free "trial" version and it messed up and it states a table doesn't exist when I click "generate" it says 'Table 'stopnzet_scripts.generator' doesn't exist' I tried looking around but really couldn't find much in the code. But this is what I found that may help me out.

```
<?php

    if($freegenerator == "" || $_SESSION['rank'] == 5){
        $freegeneratorquery = "SELECT * FROM `freegenerators`";
    }else{
        $freegeneratorquery = "SELECT * FROM `freegenerators` WHERE `id` = ".$freegenerator;
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $freegeneratorquery) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '
          <div class="col-lg-4">
              <!--user info table start-->
              <section class="panel">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                      <div class="task-thumb-details">
                          <h1>'.$row['name'].' Generator</h1>
                      </div>
                      <legend></legend>
                      <input type="text" id="freegenerator'.$row["id"].'" onclick="select_all(this)" class="text-center form-control" placeholder="username:password"></br>
                      <button id="generate'.$row["id"].'" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Generate</button></br>
                      <legend></legend>
                      <form id="flagform'.$row["id"].'" action="freegenerator.php" method="POST">
                          <input type="hidden" id="flag'.$row["id"].'" name="flagalt" value="">
                          <input type="hidden" name="freegenerator" value="'.$row["id"].'">
                          <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
                              <a id="copy'.$row["id"].'" data-clipboard-target="freegenerator'.$row["id"].'" title="Copy" class="btn btn-success">Copy</a>
                              <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick=$(this).closest("form").submit(); title="Flag as invalid" class="btn btn-danger">Flag as invalid</a>
                          </div>
                      </form>
                  </div>
              </section>
              <!--user info table end-->
          </div>
        ';
    }
?>
```

Top of page php code

```
<?php

include "inc/header.php";

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `subscriptions` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `active` = '1' AND `expires` >= '$date'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) < 0 && $_SESSION['rank'] != "5") {
header('Location: purchase.php');
}

if (isset($_POST['flagalt']) && isset($_POST['freegenerator'])){
$alt = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, str_replace("\r\n", "", urldecode($_POST['flagalt'])));
$freegeneratorid = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['freegenerator']);
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `freegenerator$freegeneratorid` SET `status` = '2' WHERE `alt` = '$alt'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
}

$totalalts = 0;

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `freegenerators`") or die(mysqli_error($con));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$result2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `freegenerator$row[id]` WHERE `status` != '0'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
$totalalts = $totalalts + mysqli_num_rows($result2);
}

?>
```

freegenerator php code

```
<?php

if($freegenerator == "" || $_SESSION['rank'] == 5){
    $freegeneratorquery = "SELECT * FROM `freegenerators`";
}else{
    $freegeneratorquery = "SELECT * FROM `freegenerators` WHERE `id` = ".$freegenerator;
}

$result = mysqli_query($con, $freegeneratorquery) or die(mysqli_error($con));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '
      <div class="col-lg-4">
          <!--user info table start-->
          <section class="panel">
              <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="task-thumb-details">
                      <h1>'.$row['name'].' Generator</h1>
                  </div>
                  <legend></legend>
                  <input type="text" id="freegenerator'.$row["id"].'" onclick="select_all(this)" class="text-center form-control" placeholder="username:password"></br>
                  <button id="generate'.$row["id"].'" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Generate</button></br>
                  <legend></legend>
                  <form id="flagform'.$row["id"].'" action="freegenerator.php" method="POST">
                      <input type="hidden" id="flag'.$row["id"].'" name="flagalt" value="">
                      <input type="hidden" name="freegenerator" value="'.$row["id"].'">
                      <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
                          <a id="copy'.$row["id"].'" data-clipboard-target="freegenerator'.$row["id"].'" title="Copy" class="btn btn-success">Copy</a>
                          <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick=$(this).closest("form").submit(); title="Flag as invalid" class="btn btn-danger">Flag as invalid</a>
                      </div>
                  </form>
              </div>
          </section>
          <!--user info table end-->
      </div>
    ';
}
?>
```

Comment: can you use `stopnzet_scripts.generator` from mysql console ?

Comment: All php code must be inside php tag `<?php ?>`

Comment: No? What do you mean? there is no stopnzet_scripts.generator. Its just a confusing process.

Comment: Rishi...... it is......

Comment: @Sightings what ?isn't `stopnzet_scripts.generator` a mysql table?

Comment: @FastSnail No, The data is supposed to be pulled from a table called 'freegenerator26' but for some reason it doesn't work. I go into developer tools and it says its trying to pull that but it just comes out with 'stopnzet_scripts.generator' doesn't exist'

Comment: @Sightings show the php code of `freegenerator.php`

Comment: @FastSnail Added to main post

Comment: @Sightings debug your code. got to the error line and check why it has unexpected value. for example print and see value of $freegeneratorid then freegenerator$freegeneratorid and so on.but depending on error line you should debug relevant codes

Comment: @FastSnail I added more code I think a line in the first set or code there is an error